# R regex: specifying output selections from wider string matches

Tags: regex, r, stringr

One for the regex enthusiasts. I have a vector of strings in the format:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" STYLE="font-size: 10px" size="10" COLOR="#FF0000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">Desired output string containing any symbols</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

I'm aware of the [perils of parsing this sort of stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) with regex.  It would however be useful to know how to efficiently extract an output sub-string of a larger string match - i.e. the contents of angle quotes `>...<` of the font tag. The best I can do is:

```
require(stringr)
strng = str_extract(strng, "<FONT.*FONT>") # select font statement
strng = str_extract(strng, ">.*<")         # select inside tags
strng = str_extract(strng, "[^/</>]+")     # remove angle quote symbols
```

What would be the simplest formula to achieve this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str_match`, not `str_extract` (or maybe `str_match_all`).  Wrap the part that you want to <del>extract</del> match in parentheses.

```
str_match(strng, "<FONT[^<>]*>([^<>]*)</FONT>")
```

---

Or parse the document and extract the contents that way.

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(strng)
fonts <- xpathSApply(doc, "//font")
sapply(fonts, function(x) as(xmlChildren(x)$text, "character"))
```

As agstudy mentioned, `xpathSApply` takes a function argument that makes things easier.

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//font", xmlValue)
```

Comment: Ah the brackets specify the output. But in that case a simpler formula is `str_match(strng, "<FONT.*>(.*)</FONT>")[1,2]`.  I did play around with the XML method but failed to get that working , so thanks for that too.

Comment: and `...[,2]` for the vector.

Comment: @geotheory There's a tradeoff of how specific you want to be in the match.  More specific matches are usually faster and have less false positive matches, but you might have a false negative if your text contains unusual characters.

Comment: Noted. I wonder Richie if you could possibly advise on [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497652/reading-kml-files-into-r?noredirect=1#comment28928052_19497652) re your XML method.  I'm working with a KML file but the XML structure is proving tricky to parse.

Comment: @RichieCotton +1!you can do shorter (omit the last line) by something like `xpathSApply(doc, "//font",xmlChildren)$text` or `xpathSApply(doc, "//font",xmlValue)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with `gsub` but I think there are too many permutations to your input vector that may cause this to break...

```
gsub( "^.*(?<=>)(.*)(?=</FONT>).*$" , "\\1" , x , perl = TRUE )
#[1] "Desired output string containing any symbols"
```

#### Explanation

- `^.*` - match any characters from the start of the string
- `(?<=>)` - positive lookbehind zero-width assertion where the subsequent match will only work if it is preceeded by this, i.e. a `>`
- `(.*)` - then match any characters (this is now a numbered capture group)...
- `(?=</FONT>)` - ...until you match `"</FONT>"`
- `.*$` - then match any characters to the end of the string

In the replacement we replace all matched stuff by numbered capture group `\\1`, and there is only one capture group which is everything between `>` and `</FONT>`.

Use at your peril.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Yes I've heard that line: "you had a problem and tried regex. now you have two problems.." :)