# R: Processing KML/KMZ Files

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I found the following link about internet connectivity in Canada over here: https://crtc.gc.ca/eng/publications/reports/policymonitoring/2020/cmr4.htm

This link contains several interesting maps - for example (https://crtc.gc.ca/cartovista/LTEProviderCountYE2019_EN/index.html):

[image]

- Apparently all data used to make the maps in this report are located here: https://crtc.gc.ca/eng/publications/reports/policyMonitoring/cmrd.htm
- I think (?) I was able to find the data used to make Map 4.2 (LTE service coverage by number of facilities-based coverage networks 2019)  :  https://applications.crtc.gc.ca/OpenData/CASP/COMMUNICATION%20MONITORING%20REPORTS/Telecommunications%20Overview/English/data-mobile-and-broadband-availability.xlsx?_ga=2.166868798.1495853269.1687059710-2061002955.1687059710

**My Question:**

- I am working with the R programming language - I am interested in trying to extract the "geospatial information" used to create this map (e.g. shapefile, polygons, latitude/longitude of each circle, color of each circle, etc.) and view this data in R.
- Once I have done this, I would be interested in then trying to re-create this map myself using different libraries in R (e.g. leaflet)
- At the moment, it seems quite difficult and unclear how to search through all the data sources provided - but using the KML files linked in this map (as well as through the html of this map https://crtc.gc.ca/cartovista/LTEProviderCountYE2019_EN/index.html), is it possible to somehow "decompose and extract" all relevant "geospatial information" in R?

In the end, I would like to have a shapefile within R that contains the boundaries of the different geospatial polygons used in this map, along with information about the "values" of each polygon (e.g. yellow, blue, green "blobs"). Then, I could use the leaflet library to make this map myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading KML files into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497652/reading-kml-files-into-r)

Comment: @ Mark Hill: Thank you for your reply! I am currently looking at previous posts on stackoverflow that involve processing KML files in R and seeing how applicable these are to my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: cool no worries! I flagged this as a duplicate :-)